# Trimming strings in non-contiguous spreadsheet ranges

Tags: strings, vba, excel, formatting

This code is tested and works, but I am needing some guidance on simplifying these loops with non-contiguous ranges. I was thinking an `array` might be better, but I haven't had enough experience with `Arrays` to know where to start with one. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Dim r As Range
Dim v
For Each r In JHACheck.Range("M7:M32")
    v = r.Value
    If v <> "" Then
        If Not r.HasFormula Then
            r.Value = Trim(v)
        End If
    End If
Next r

For Each r In JHACheck.Range("M35:M41")
    v = r.Value
    If v <> "" Then
        If Not r.HasFormula Then
            r.Value = Trim(v)
        End If
    End If
Next r

For Each r In JHACheck.Range("R35:R41")
    v = r.Value
    If v <> "" Then
        If Not r.HasFormula Then
            r.Value = Trim(v)
        End If
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Are the ranges the same every time you run the macro?  if they are you could try `For Each r In JHACheck["M7:M32,M35:M41R35:R41"]`  It wouldn't decrease the speed but it would reduce the duplication of code.  Otherwise you would need to create an array of ranges to reduce the duplication.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try when I'm back in the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small amount of data doesn't merit the use of arrays. I agree with R. Roe comment on combining the Ranges.

But first:

- V is a very unhelpful helper variable, I would get rid of it.
- Personally, I use `r` to iterate rows row, `c` to iterate columns and `cell` to iterate cells in a Range
- Techiniquelly, the two if statements are more efficient than combining a single If statement.  Realistically, it will not make a noticeable difference with your code.   I would combine the Ifs and save the clutter.

---

> ```
> Dim cell As Range
> For Each cell In JHACheck.Range("M7:M32,M35:M41,R35:R41")
>     If Not r.HasFormula And cell.Value <> "" Then cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
> Next
> ```

Comment: Thanks!  For some strange reason I was under the wrong assumption that I couldnt loop through non-contiguous cells like this.

Comment: @ZackE I think that they changed it in recent years.  I'm pretty sure that in Excel 2007, we had to iterate over each cell of each area of a range,

Answer (score 2):

It's clear you're performing the same operation over different ranges of cells. So I'd separate that logic in a `Function` which you can call with any range you like. Using arrays achieve a speed up if the ranges are large, but for now wait until you think you need it. (Needing to check the cell for `.HasFormula` will slow down using an array in any case.)

The code below shows the trimming logic isolated to a single function. The logic is no different from yours with the exception of more clear variable names.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    TrimTheseCells JHACheck.Range("M7:M32")
    TrimTheseCells JHACheck.Range("M35:M41")
    TrimTheseCells JHACheck.Range("R35:R41")
End Sub

Private Sub TrimTheseCells(ByRef thisRange As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In thisRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If Not cell.HasFormula Then
                cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```